# How to get total during a foreach

Tags: php

I am learning PHP, and trying to output the total of the "Price" column.

Here's what it looks like right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJsJd.jpg

Here's the code:

```
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            $rows[] = $row;

        }

        foreach($rows as $row){

            $food = $row["food"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $id = $row['id'];

            if(!empty($_POST[$id])){
            $qtyPrice = $price * $_POST[$id];
            $qty = $_POST[$id];

            }

            echo "<tr>
            <td>$food</td>
            <td>$qty</td>
            <td>$$qtyPrice</td>
        </tr>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do 2 loops. You are setting the array with the 1st while loop and then using a 2nd foreach loop just to read it and display the data.

It will be more efficient to use the while loop to generate your html table directly.

You can use `$total += $qtyPrice (same as $total = $total + $qtyPrice)`.
Just remember to set it to 0 before the loop.

```
$total = 0;

 while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

        $food = $row["food"];
        $price = $row["price"];
        $id = $row['id'];

        if(!empty($_POST[$id])){
        $qtyPrice = $price * $_POST[$id];
        $qty = $_POST[$id];

        $total += $qtyPrice;

        echo "<tr>
        <td>$food</td>
        <td>$qty</td>
        <td>$$qtyPrice</td>
    </tr>";
    }

//display the total in its separate row
echo "<tr><td>Total:</td><td></td><td>$total</td></tr>";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

set a variable before starting the loop, and adding the qtyPrice at it. Print that variable after exit the loop

```
    $total = 0;

foreach($rows as $row){

            $food = $row["food"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $id = $row['id'];

            if(!empty($_POST[$id])){
            $qtyPrice = $price * $_POST[$id];
            $total += $qtyPrice;
            $qty = $_POST[$id];

            }

            echo "<tr>
            <td>$food</td>
            <td>$qty</td>
            <td>$$qtyPrice</td>
        </tr>";
        }
    echo $total;
```